# Is there a way in JMeter to get the response message from the network tab?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to get the error message from the network tab in JMeter:
[image]

I have inserted the response assertion looking for a 200 or 201. However, when a test fails, it only tells me it is looking for one of the values, but not a message like in the response section of the network tab. For example, if it is a bad request, I see the 400, but no message like "uid cannot be empty, name cannot be empty". Is there a way to pull this information in JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "normal" [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you cannot, if you want to apply some custom logic you need to perform some custom scripting.

For example if you want to add response body to the Assertion message you can play the following trick:

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) **after** the Response Assertion
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
       if (assertionResult.isFailure()) {
           assertionResult.setFailureMessage(assertionResult.getFailureMessage() + 
                   System.getProperty('line.separator') + 
                   'Response data:' + 
                   System.getProperty('line.separator') + 
                   prev.getResponseDataAsString())
       }
   }
   ```

That's it, the above code will add the response data to any failing assertion, hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Going forward you might want to migrate all the assertion logic into the JSR223 Assertion and Groovy, see [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more details.